# Scala doesn't run as expected

Tags: scala

The entry point of `some.scala` is defined below:

```
object MyApp extends App {
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```

1. If I run

   ```
   $ scala some.scala
   ```

   Scala quits quietly, then compile it via,

   ```
   $ scalac some.scala
   ...
   MyApp.class
   MyApp$delayedInit$body.class
   ...
   ```
2. If I then run

   ```
   $ scala MyApp
   ```

   it works.

Does the `delayedInit` class above prevent case 1 from running?

Comment: If the source is replaced by `object MyApp { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hello, World!")  }`, the case 1 will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `scala` man page:

> If -howtorun: is left as the default (guess), then the scala command
>   will check whether a file of the specified name exists.  If it does,
>   then it will treat it as a script file ...

So in your case `scala` is processing `some.scala` as a script file, not much different from typing it in REPL. It will define the object `MyApp` but won't execute it. Try to put a single line in `some.scala`:

```
println("Hello, World!")
```

and run it as `scala some.scala`